# Switching between excel sheets in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to generate excel sheets (.xls format) and I have used the following code snippet to create Hyperlinks that link to a different sheet in the same document/workbook.

```
HSSFSheet summarySheet = workbook.createSheet("Target Sheet");
Hyperlink targetLink = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_DOCUMENT);
targetLink.setAddress("'Target Sheet'!A1");
```

There are more than one sheet that I'm creating and upon clicking the Hyperlink it shows the respective sheet. However, I'm having difficulty in traversing to the different sheets that I have created with the above lines of code. I need to populate those sheets with data from the database but I don't know how to switch between those sheets.

Any help would be appreciated. Please do let me know before you downvote/if there is anything wrong with my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the sheets in existing xls you can use the HSSFWORKBOOK method getSheet("Sheet Name"):

```
HSSFSheet linkedSheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet name");
```

once you have the linked sheet you can add the entries onto it.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that method.